# how to get the peers from an torrent tracker

Tags: java, php, bittorrent

how can i get the torrent peers from an tracker .....
say i have

```
hash value 76a36f1d11c72eb5663eeb4cf31e351321efa3a3
```

and an tracker `info as http://tracker.openbittorrent.com/announce` 
how can i get the peers

Comment: In what language, which library, what application?

Comment: can i get it using java...i am not sure .. first i need to know to can i get it ....

Answer (score 6):

Check the [protocol specification](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_HTTP.2FHTTPS_Protocol).

Comment: ya but if i use http://tracker.openbittorrent.com/announce?info_hash=76a36f1d11c72eb5663eeb4cf31e351321efa3a3
it shows error...

Comment: @rap if you check the link I gave you you'll see your example lacks many required parameters, like the peer_id or the event. No wonder it's an invalid request.

Comment: Not only that, you have to send the actual value of the hash as a GET parameter. "76a36f1d11c72eb5663eeb4cf31e351321efa3a3" is a **hexadecimal representation** of the hash, but the tracker protocol specifies that you need to send **the value of the hash** (=bytestring). So you have to first decode the hexadecimal representation and then URL encode it: `urllib.urlencode( [('info_hash', '76a36f1d11c72eb5663eeb4cf31e351321efa3a3'.decode('hex'))] ) == 'info_hash=v%A3o%1D%11%C7.%B5f%3E%EBL%F3%1E5%13%21%EF%A3%A3' # in Python.`