# Translating Hexadecimal To Value In Vb.net [For Torrent Trackers]

Tags: vb.net, tracker

Im basically trying to achieve this : [how to get the peers from an torrent tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451354/how-to-get-the-peers-from-an-torrent-tracker)

Im stuck here :

> Not only that, you have to send the actual value of the hash as a GET parameter. "76a36f1d11c72eb5663eeb4cf31e351321efa3a3" is a hexadecimal representation of the hash, but the tracker protocol specifies that you need to send the value of the hash (=bytestring). So you have to first decode the hexadecimal representation and then URL encode it: urllib.urlencode( [('info_hash', '76a36f1d11c72eb5663eeb4cf31e351321efa3a3'.decode('hex'))] ) == 'info_hash=v%A3o%1D%11%C7.%B5f%3E%EBL%F3%1E5%13%21%EF%A3%A3' # in Python.

I have researched quite alot and due to my newbish coding skills I can't manage to do the following in vb.net. Could anyone please enlighten me ?

I need to do the same thing :
Conversion from hexadecimal representation to the bytestring value of the hash.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised there was not an easier way to turn a hex string into a byte array, but I didn't locate one quickly so here is the hard way:

```
  Dim hex As String = "76a36f1d11c72eb5663eeb4cf31e351321efa3a3"

  'prepend leading zero if needed
  If hex.Length Mod 2 <> 0 Then
     hex = " " & hex
  End If


  Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte((hex.Length \ 2) - 1) {}
  For byteNum As Int32 = 0 To bytes.Length - 1

     bytes(byteNum) = Byte.Parse(hex.Substring(byteNum * 2, 2), 
           Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)

  Next

  'convert to an ansi string and escape
  Dim final As String =Uri.EscapeDataString( 
        System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes))
```